# Auto-create a post with last 10 images in WordPress directory

Tags: directory, wp-insert-post, post-content

I want to create something to help me auto-create a post with 10 last images hosted in some directory (in my server or WordPress), this code I found helps to post an image but not many images if anyone could help me.

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'create_post');
function create_post( $attach_ID ) {

    $attachment = get_post( $attach_ID );

    $my_post_data = array(
                'post_title' => $attachment->post_title,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_category' => array('0'),
                'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post_data );

    // attach media to post
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $attach_ID,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
    ) );

    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_ID );

    return $attach_ID;
}
```

Comment: your code adds a Featured Image to the post, but you want to add more(10) images then you have to get attachments and filter the post content in which you want them. Also when do you want to update the post content?

Comment: It's not my code i just found it on stackexchange .. yes can you help me with the code, i can't seem to find it anywhere, for the When i guess i can hook it to a Cron job ? somehow i think .. thanks for your reply

Comment: you can get the last 10 attachments url from table wp_posts where **post_type = attachment** and **post_mime_type = image**. Then you can insert them inside a new post using **wp_insert_post** or a already existing post using **wp_update_post**. If you need help we can continue this conversation in chat